# MongoDB match values inside an array/array of objects

Tags: mongodb

I´m working on a project, and since I´m new to the MongoDB i have a question on querying the database. I would like to query database like this

```
db.getCollection('achievmenets2').find("id":20)
```

that will search the whole document if the id that is 20 exists and returns the object

this is how the database looks

```
 -Achievement Category
    - id
    - Achievements_Array(Contains achievements with the ID that im gonna search for)
 -Achievement Category2
    - id
    - Achievements_Array(Contains achievements with the ID that im gonna search for)
```

Thanks for answer

Comment: I cannot find any question statement in your post.

Comment: How do i query whole document with nested objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have a collection test with the following data.

**test**

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5a1172f17780777507a9be7a"),
  "name" : "Rob",
  "friends" : [ 
    "Jamie", 
    "Avisha"
  ]
}
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5a1172f17780777507a9be7c"),
  "name" : "Kim",
  "friends" : [ 
    "Jose", 
    "Avisha"
  ]
}
```

You have to query the collection to fetch results having "Avisha" in friends array. To achieve this you can use the `$in` operator of mongoDB.

The query would look like

```
db.getCollection('test').find({friends: {$in: ['Avisha']}})
```

It will give you 2 results. Similarly, you can replace "test" with your collection name, "friends" with your achievement array and "Avisha" with the id you want to search.

And suppose the friends array contains objects, for example

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5a1172f17780777507a9be7a"),
  "name" : "Rob",
  "friends" : [ 
    {"name": "Jamie"}, 
    {"name": "Avisha"}
  ]
}
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5a1172f17780777507a9be7c"),
  "name" : "Kim",
  "friends" : [ 
    {"name": "Jose"}, 
    {"name": "Avisha"}
  ]
}
```

You can use the following query to fetch the result.

```
db.getCollection('test').find({"friends.name": {$in: ['Avisha']}})
```

Comment: what if I need to fetch data of avisha and Jose from the second array ?